# HNN extensions which are free products

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

which HNN-extensions are free products? this question is related with another still unsolved about Nielsen-Thruston-reducibility and connected-sum-irreducibility of 3d-torus- bundles...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This might help.

**Lemma** If $A$ does not split freely and $C$ is a non-trivial subgroup of $A$ then the HNN extension $G=A*_C$ does not split freely.

The proof uses Bass--Serre theory---see Serre's book *Trees* from 1980.

*Proof.*  Let $T$ be the Bass--Serre tree of a free splitting of $G$.  Because $A$ does not split freely, $A$ stabilizes some unique vertex $v$.  But $C$ is non-trivial, so $C$ also stabilizes a unique vertex, which must be $v$.   Therefore,  $G$ stabilizes $v$, which means the free splitting was trivial. *QED*

A similar argument shows the following.

**Lemma** If $ A*_C $ splits non-trivially as an amalgamated free product $ A' *_{C'} B'$ then either $A$ splits over $C'$ or $C$ is conjugate into $C'$.

Comment: i must admit that i didn't seek until find, but lot of thanks H.W.
i feel that MO put the advance of all "mathemagizians" in a better pace...

Comment: juan, are you referring to the Phantom Tollbooth?

Comment: i just check on Phantom Toollbooth (google) but i still don't see how my comments make you -Prof- think what i am refering...

Comment: There's a character in the book called "The Mathemagician".

Comment: we all are mathemagiZians :)

Answer (score 1):

Let me add an explicit partial solution to the question above: for a torus bundle $E$ over the circle, the fundamental group of $E$ can't be a free product of groups, because if it were, the fundamental subgroup of the fiber would be a free product (by the Kurosch's theorem) which is impossible for the torus, then $E$ isn't a connected sum, hence irreducible.

At least the HNN extensions which are free products can't be torus bundles, and in fact, no other surface bundles unless the surface be the 2-sphere

Comment: Another way of seeing this is to look at $\pi_2$.  A non-trivial free product has an essential 2-sphere, whereas it's easy to see that the universal cover of a torus bundle is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$.